# Vout/Vin equation in time domain vs frequency domain

Tags: transfer-function, math

While studying op-amp circuits, I notice a pattern between the Vout/Vin equation in time domain and the frequency domain. For example:

[image]

(images from *Microelectronics* by Bahzad Razavi, 2/e)

The transfer function of this circuit in the frequency domain is \$-R_1 \times C1 \times s\$ meaning \$V_{out} = -R_1 \times C_1 \times s \times V_{\text{in}}\$.

In the time domain, \$V_{out} = -R_1 \times C_1 \times \left(\frac {dV_{\text{in}}}{dt}\right)\$

It is as if \$s \times V_{in}\$ corresponds to \$\frac{dV_{\text{in}}}{dt}\$. There are other examples where \$V_{\text{in}}\$ in the time domain corresponds to \$V_{\text{in}}\$ in the frequency domain and \$\frac{V_{\text{in}}}{s}\$ corresponds to integrals of \$V_{\text{in}}\$.

It seems like \$s\$ in the frequency domain means derivatives(?) in the time domain.

Is this a general fact or just coincidence? If they are not coincidences, how are they related mathematically? Some kind of transform? If so, why is the transformation correct?  I think there is a deeper connection between the two that I don't realize yet.

Comment: Welcome to the EE Stack Exchange. Questions that require a textbook to answer are usually not a good fit for the site, May I ask why do you doubt this Laplace transformation?

Comment: I didn't think this a Laplace transformation. I thought the s-domain of Laplace transformation has nothing to do with this, just happened to use the same character s. Why is the end result of Laplace in the frequency domain?

Comment: Yes, multiply by s is equivalent to differentiation wrt time. Likewise, multiply by 1/s is integration. See properties of the Laplace transform.

Answer (score 2):

By definition,

$$
s=j\omega+\sigma
$$

where \$\sigma\$ is the Neper frequency and it's related to decaying, and \$\omega\$ is the angular frequency and it's related to oscillation.

At steady state there's no decaying i.e. for steady state analysis it's taken as zero. So,

$$
s=j\omega
$$

And this comes from the derivative of famous complex exponential:

$$
\frac{d}{dt}e^{j\omega t}={j\omega}\ e^{j\omega t}
$$

Therefore

$$
\frac{d}{dt}=j\omega=s
$$